# Como substituir o número de letras de uma palavra por um caractere?

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms

Estou fazendo um jogo da forca, vamos supor que eu digite o nome "joão" em uma caixa de *text*, logo depois aperto um botão e quero que na caixa de "texto 2" apareça "_ _ _ _", então quero que apareçam o mesmo numero de *underlines* que o numero de letras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe um [construtor pronto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_) para fazer isto então é muito simples.

```
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var texto = "carambola";
        var adivinha = new String('_', texto.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(adivinha);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4gnWzD). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0qHTfm). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ReplicateChar.cs).

Se fizer um laço adicionando *strings* é mais lento e faz um estrago no *garbage collector*. Pode não ser importante fazer em um joguinho muito simples, mas se aprende errado em algo simples vai reproduzir em algo que importe mais. Pelo menos poderia usar [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) neste caso, mas também seria um exagero.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [string.Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx) para saber o tamanho da palavra que você possui.
Depois você pode `Iterar` em cima desse tamanho escrevendo `"_"`

Exemplor:

```
for(int i=0; i< string.Legth; i++)
{
  // aqui você pode criar um string igual ao seu exemplo
  novaString += "_";
}
```

Ou então com `foreach`

```
foreach(Char caracter in SuaString)
{
  // aqui você pode criar um string igual ao seu exemplo
  novaString += "_";
}
```

Ai você pode usar sua `novaString` para mostrar na tela o exemplo, existem outras formas de fazer, depende de como você vai mostrar esse texto.

Answer (score 2):

Além do que já foi respondido anteriormente você pode usar expressão regular 'Regex' com a função replace, substituindo os caracteres.

```
string txt = "Primeiro Teste";
string forca=   Regex.Replace(txt, "[\\w]", "_");

O resultado é: ________ _____
```

Se preferir fazer similar a forca basta colocar um espaço após o carácter Undescore:

```
string txt = "Primeiro Teste";
string teste2 = Regex.Replace(txt, "[\\w]", "_ ");

O resultado é: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  _ _ _ _ _
```